# Why my page is not correctly loading

Tags: asp.net, plesk

I setup a site on a new server using Plesk and I'm using site preview function to test it:

https://72.10.53.83:8443/sitepreview/http/getb12.com.au/Default.aspx

or

https://72.10.53.83:8443/sitepreview/http/getb12.com.au/Default.aspx

I do not understand why my aspx page is not interpreted correctly...

Do you see any reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong server type. The server in question is running Apache in a Linux environment, not the Microsoft environment you need.

The server type is visible in the response header, I just checked it with Safari's Web Inspector to be sure.